# H-bridge amplifier DC oscillations

Tags: amplifier, h-bridge, oscillation

I have designed a simple amplifier (maybe too simple) that has bad DC oscillation (instability). I attach a picture with the schematic. It's not the entire amplifier but only the final stage, where DC oscillations occur.

The V_out_L or R node should be at 200 mV but it's not stable: the voltage range randomly from 0.02 to 1 V at a frequency that can be observed with a multimeter. The VBE multiplier is set with a trimmer to get 10 mA quiescent current on MOSFET, but oscillations persist also with the MOSFET in the off state!

After a while the VBE multiplier died, so there is a serious problem. This happens also without load. The circuit is made on a PCB with SMD components and a good 4-layer layout.

Do you see any issue in the schematic that can lead to these oscillations?

[image]

Comment: Have you simulated the circuit? Does it oscillate in the simulation too? Or is this the simulation? If yes, please show oscillogram.

Comment: For starters, it looks like you got your pmos and nmos swapped.

Comment: @LetterSized this is an amplifier and not a digital H bridge.

Comment: Vbe multiplier is normally supposed to be driven with a constant current source.

Comment: It should output around VCC/2 so you should first check if the low frequency on the output comes from the power supply itself. Then, I don't see any decoupling or snubber, so check for high frequency oscillations with a scope, because the multimeter can read high frequency as random DC. I'm also interested in seeing the layout, how did you couple the SMD 5551 transistors with the heatsink?

Comment: 1) Yes I simulated the circuit and of course there isn't oscillations neither in DC neither with an applied signal.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect the DC output to be particularly stable without any feedback. The source degeneration resistors only drop around 2 mV at a bias current of 10 mA, which is a miniscule fraction of the threshold voltage. Any temperature drift will cause a large change in output voltage.

Comment: 2) I know for the costant current but I need for a more simple design. Do you think a design with resistors to generate the current could be a problem? 3)According to simulation it should output 200 mV in DC (why VCC/2 ?) The low frequency don't come from power supply. Decoupling capacitors are not shown but are mounted on the board. I use a custom heatsink to couple VBE transistors to power MOS. 
of the board is not mounted. Load still not mounted.

Comment: 4) Now I'm removing power  MOS and a stranger thing happen: without M1 and M2 I read a voltage on the V_out_L!! How is possible, is an open circuit! This voltage oscillates. The other bridge

Comment: I'm not expect an absolute stable output, but It change randomly from few mV to few Volts, so there is not only a temperature related issue, no?

Comment: It certainly can be temperature related. You have your Vbe multiplier, which will drift with temperature (Vbe will drift a few mV per degC), the FET threshold voltages will drift with temperature, and you've got two of them to worry about. In such a push pull amplifier, you very often have some feedback path to force the DC output to be 0V (or whatever you want it to be). That feedback could, for example, be from the output to an inverting stage that drives this power stage (must be an inverting stage, otherwise you get positive feedback).

Comment: *"Vbe multiplier died"*?... In this circuit, one of the very few ways to destroy the Vbe multiplier transistor is high-frequency oscillations. Debug it with an oscilloscope.

Comment: HF oscillations? They can come from Power MOS, but I didn't see nothig at the scope. Maybe they are at a very high frequency. I just replaced MOS with BJT and oscillations persist.